# Plot lap times for car races

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that holds laptimes for different cars that drove at a track

```
    car_type    tires   lap     lap_time_seconds
    Mercedes    A       1       46
    Mercedes    A       2       44
    Mercedes    A       3       42
    Mercedes    B       1       39
    Mercedes    B       2       41
    BMW         A       1       44
    BMW         A       2       40
    BMW         B       1       37
    BMW         B       2       37 
    BMW         B       3       38
    BMW         B       4       36
    VW          A       1       55
    VW          A       2       53
    VW          A       3       54
    VW          B       1       49 
    VW          B       2       50
    VW          B       3       48
```

For each car two types of tires were used: `A` and `B`. Some cars did more laps with the type `A` type tires and some did more laps with type `B`.

I would like to plot the laptimes for each car. On the x-axis I would like to have the lap number, and on the y-axis the lap time in seconds. I would like to discern between tire types `A` and `B` using a regular line for type `A` and a dotted line for type `B`. The lines corresponding to each car should have unique colors.

If I run

```
sns.lineplot(x = 'lap', y = 'lap_time_seconds', hue = 'tires', data = cars)
```

I get the following result:

[image]

This comes closed to what I want: each car has its own color. However, instead of showing each tire type for each car as a dotted vs non-dotted line, the laptimes are averaged for each car.

**Question:** How do I plot two lines for each car, indicating the tires, instead of showing the average?